# Как вставить картинку в указанном месте, чтобы она была как фон?

Tags: html, css

[image: снимок]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.е два блока - 1 поверх другого?
Попробуй:

```css
.olololo {
  z-index: 2;
  background: url(ololo.jpg) repeat-x center center;
  width: 100% height:500px;
}

.trololo {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="olololo">
  <div class="trololo"></div>
  <div>
```

Индекс 2 будет над индекс 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
background: url(link_to_pic.jpg) repeat-x center center;
}
```

или я не так понял? Тогда поясните свой чертеж.

Comment: То что серое, это блок. А то что заштрихованно, это то, где должно распологаться изображение.